# Planar flows implementation to approximate Gamma distribution

Tags: normalizing-flow

I've been trying to implement [image: Planar flows] in order to approximate Gamma distribution but the problem I've been encountering is that the hyperbolic tangent activation function that I used gives negative values, which is unacceptable for sampling from Gamma distribution. What other activation functions can I use in order to avoid this drawback and to keep the bijectivity of the following planar flows? Or if anyone has already implemented the planar flows to approximate Gamma distribution I would appreciate it if you could share the code or guide me.

Answer (score 0):

from all normalizing flows repos that I have studied, I'd recommend vincent's implementation and here's the planar [one](https://github.com/VincentStimper/normalizing-flows/blob/master/normflows/flows/planar.py). Lastly, about the Gamma, you can just set it as the target distribution.